# Using the same variable across multiple scripts

Tags: bash, shell

What is the best practice for using the same bash variable (that is NOT an environment variable) across multiple scripts which call each other sequentially? Should this variable be defined in every script or function in order to keep them atomically reusable?

For example, let's say that I have one script which sources a `functions.sh` script with many smaller reusable functions.

```sh
#script_1

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

country="${1}"

. ${DIR}/functions.sh

function_1
function_2 ${country}

#functions.sh

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

function_1() {
echo "The country is ${country}"
}

function_2(){
local country="${1}"

if [[ ${country^^} == "UK" ]]; then
    echo "Fish and Chips"
else
    echo "Try local food"
fi
}
```

My question is: should the `${country}` variable be defined locally in each atomic function in the `functions.sh` source file?

When those functions are called, `${country}` is already defined in the initial script, so I wouldn't have to pass it on as a parameter. I'm thinking that each of those scripts should not depend on some variable maybe being defined previously, but they should be given all the information they require via parameters, so that they can be reused easily.

Also, should it be defined as `country` or `COUNTRY`?

Comment: This is the same as using global variables in any other language. You should try to avoid them, parameters are generally better.

Comment: All-uppercase variables are conventionally reserved for environment variables.

Comment: @Barmar so to sum up, you are saying: keep the variable in lowercase (since it's not an environment variable) and it's best to define and pass the variable as a parameter in each function instead of relying on it already existing in the context in which the script is run.

Comment: I'd go further and tell you not to use ALLCAPS_VARS at all. It's too easy to use `PATH=/path/to/file; DIR=$(dirname "$PATH")` and then you wonder why your script suddenly emits "dirname: not found"